# Build a collapsible notification menu like Google Weather

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, custom-notification

I am developing a simple Android app and I'm trying to build a notification exactly like Google weather looks like on Android Oreo:

- should be collapsed by default
- should be grayed out
- when notification is expanded, the notification subtext should be displayed as content

[image]

[image]

I had a look on the official Android docs (https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#java) but I haven't found exactly what I need.

Is the grayed out notification something specific to system background processes? 
Can someone please provide a hint regarding this notification style type (especially on the expanded thing)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create a `Notification Channel` with its `priority` set to `IMPORTANCE_MIN`, then use that channel to create your notification.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676819/android-o-single-line-notification-like-the-android-system-usb-charging-t) for more explanation.