# Start foreground service without popping up a notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service

An android foreground service needs a notification, which is fine, but I would rather have it go directly to the notification background without first obscuring the UI for 3 seconds.

Is there a combination of settings for the notification builder and or the notification channel, which will give me the small icon in the notification bar as well as the notification, when expanding the notification list, but without showing a notification on top of the ui for about three seconds?

My issue is not that I want to hide anything, but rather that the application is in use by the user after the foreground service is being started, so the popup is annoying.

Comment: You might get that with a low-priority notification.

Comment: check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676819/android-o-single-line-notification-like-the-android-system-usb-charging-t

Comment: Thanks to you both. It seems that setting it low does solve the "issue". Then it does not show the notification icon, though, which I thought was a failure, but is apparently expected in android 13 for foreground services.